# Cannot get HTML anchors to work when opening URL with Chrome Ember.js

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, anchor

I have the following simple ember application (only an application.hbs file).

Here I have several anchors and would like the user to click on one and get to that section of the page (much like what is used in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Gaye#Midnight_Love)).

Here's the problem. If I click one of the links at the top, it works. However, if I am in Chrome and I type in an anchor url (I.E. `localhost:4200/#midnight_love`), the the URL will load the Ember app, but fail to jump to the anchor. I have found that this only occurs in Chrome and that the site will jump to the anchor in both Firefox and Internet Explorer. All the code needed to recreate this problem is given below if you simply copy/paste into your application.hbs of an ember app.

Also note that this exact same code would work across all browsers, had I pasted this code simply into an HTML file.

**Application.hbs**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#Early_career">1 <span class="toctext">Early career</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#Initial_success">2 <span class="toctext">Initial success</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#What's_Going_On_and_subsequent_success">3 <span class="toctext"><i>What's Going On</i> and subsequent success</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#Last_Motown_recordings_and_European_exile">4 <span class="toctext">Last Motown recordings and European exile</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#Midnight_Love">5 <span class="toctext"><i>Midnight Love</i></span></a></li>
</ul>

<h2><span id="Early_career">Early_career</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="Initial_success"></span>Initial_success</h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="What's_Going_On_and_subsequent_success">What's_Going_On_and_subsequent_success</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="Last_Motown_recordings_and_European_exile">Last_Motown_recordings_and_European_exile</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="">Foo</span></h2>
<h2><span id="Midnight_Love">Midnight_Love</span></h2>
```

Comment: I've just tested this again in Firefox and it does in fact fail to jump to the anchor when entered from the URL

Comment: your `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Gaye#Midnight_Love` example and your `application.hbs` code works the same way accross all browsers. What difference did you see ?

Comment: In Chrome, when I open a brand new tab and type in ‘localhost:4200/#Midnight_love’ it will remains at the top of the page. What I want it to do is jump to the “midnight_love” section.

Comment: please check my answer and verify it if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `window.location` with `window.location.hash`, paste the below code in your 
`controller/application.js`

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    $(document).ready( function( ) {
      if (window.location.hash)
        window.location = window.location.hash;
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: any reason for the controller and not the route?

Comment: you can even write the same piece of code in the route